# Matching Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning

given a job opening w/ skill requirements, what is the best way (using ML or any data science approach) for me to match it against our company's internal skill database and return the list of employees that has either met or exceeded the criteria?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) can be used (and has been used) to match employee competence with employee expectations.

The real challenge is to analyze he unstructured job description, and CVs.